# Cohomology of Grassman manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am considering the restriction homomorphism
$H^p(G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)) \leftarrow H^p(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}))$, where the $G_n(-)$ are the relevant Grassman manifolds. Does anyone know of conditions on $p,k$ which ensure that this map is in fact an isomorphism?

Comment: Have you checked Milnor-Stasheff? I think $p < k$ should suffice